# Retrieving each row that appears under certain word

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a question, I have 1 column that has a repeat of a word ("order") several times(but has other data as well), and I want the information in the row that appears 1 row under that row where *order* appears along with 3 rows under the word *order*,

I want to get the first and third row that appear under the word order, in the example below I would want 1 and 5, along with 3 and 4, I want this to be done using 2 separate functions, one to get the first row under each word order, and another to get the third row under the word order

how would I go about doing this? I would like a function for this.

[I added the random letters after the numbers to indicate that each "set" does not have the same number of lines in between each order]

I had something figured out where I would just use a function to see if the word order was 1 line above each, and if so it gave me the result of the current line, and then I took the entire column copied and pasted (values only), and then did a *go to special* to get the non blanks, however I would like an easier solution.

example

(COLUMN A, only)
Order
**1**
5
**3**
4
2
a
b
c
d
e
Order
**5**
2
**4**
7
8
a
b
c

Desired Result
(Column B)
1
5

(Column C)
3
4

Comment: `I want the information in the row that appears 1 row under that row where appears along with 3 rows under` . It seems hard to imagine .Can you show a desired result?

Comment: I added my desired result and reformatted my *column A*
Desired Result
(Column B)
1
3

(Column C)
5
4

Comment: How many times can "Order" appear

Comment: Up to 120 times, 

edited my desired result, I made an error on posting my correct desired result, the one shown in the actual post is now correct.

Comment: So each time Order appear, its two related values below it go one more column over to the right?

Comment: No, I should probably simplify my question a little, its first related value goes 1 column over to the right, and its 2nd related value goes 2 columns over,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This formula will probably work for you, let's try it

```
=INDEX($A$1:$A$26,AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW($A$1:$A$26)/($A$1:$A$26="Order"),COLUMN(A$1))+2*ROW(A1)-1)
```

[image]

**Update:**

```
=INDEX($A$1:$A$26,AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW($A$1:$A$26)/($A$1:$A$26="Order"),ROW(A1))+2*COLUMN(A$1)-1)
```

[image]

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thank you, I did make an edit to my desired result, because I made an error, this would work for my old desired result.  I would like the *1 5 3 * to go down(col B), instead of over, and the *3 4 1* to go down instead of over (col C)

Answer (score 1):

Array-enter both formulas...

In cell `B1`:

```
=INDEX($A$1:$A$99,1+SMALL(IF($A$1:$A$99="order",ROW($A$1:$A$99)-MIN(ROW($A$1:$A$99))+1),ROW()))
```

In cell `C1`:

```
=INDEX($A$1:$A$99,3+SMALL(IF($A$1:$A$99="order",ROW($A$1:$A$99)-MIN(ROW($A$1:$A$99))+1),ROW()))
```

Copy both down as far as you need.